# Why is my UL menu overlapping other elements?

Tags: html, css

Why is my UL menu overlapping with the content div? Am I missing part of the structure to separate header/content?

http://jsfiddle.net/DBdHs/

CSS

```
.wrapper { margin: 0 auto; width: 80%; margin-top: 2em !important; }

#top-nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #f5f5f5;
}

#top-nav li {
    float:left;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #414141;
}

#top-nav li span {
    padding-bottom: .4em;
    padding-left: 3em;
    padding-right: 3em;
}

#top-nav li:hover span{
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #FF9A00;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    min-height: 150px;
    padding: 25px;
}

.row { width: 100%;}​

<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <ul id="top-nav">
        <li><span>home</span></li>
        <li><span>photos</span></li>
        <li><span>projects</span></li>
        <li><span>about me</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

<div id="content">Welcome to my home on the internet.</div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Add this to your CSS.

You're not clearing your floats. You could add a clearing div (`clear: both;`) after the menu, or add `overflow: hidden`; to your header.

Here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/DBdHs/1/

Answer (score 1):

Put `#content{clear:both;}` into your css, so the body will stay always below the header.

Comment: This won't fix the header though. That will still be collapsed. Adding a clearing div IN the header will fix that, as will overflow: hidden;

Comment: You can see what I mean by adding a background to the header and using both methods.